# How to generate primitive meshes in unity with 3 to 16 vertices automatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

At the moment I generate the meshes (3,4,5 vertices) for myself, I look for the vertices and generate the meshes.

My problem is that I want to generate meshes like this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecagon (and below: 15,14,13.. vertices) 
and I dont want to do this per hand. Is there a way or a trick, how I can do this with code? I used this: https://github.com/CiaccoDavide/Unity-UI-Polygon but I can not add colliders and get the actual mesh which is generated there.

Comment: The algorithm you have to write on your own but than you can simply [create a custom mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html)

Comment: My next problem is that I dont know the vertices of an hexadecagon ( or an pentadecagon etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to fit your points onto a unit circle, and then scale if desired.

Given a number of vertices >= 3, the angle between each vertex is 360/(number of vertices)

e.g., for 5 vertices, each vertex must be 72 degrees apart.

Now, with a starting angle of 0 degrees, for each vertex, your x-coordinate is the cosine of your starting angle, and your y-coordinate is the sine of your starting angle. After each vertex, increment your starting angle by the above-calculated angle.

Here's some Matlab code which demonstrates what I'm saying for a polygon containing 13 vertices:

```
num_verts = 13;

angle = 360/num_verts;

vertices = zeros(num_verts+1,2); % extra vertex just to plot the complete polygon
for ii=1:num_verts
    vertices(ii,1) = cosd(angle*ii);
    vertices(ii,2) = sind(angle*ii);
end
vertices(end,:) = vertices(1,:);

figure;
plot(vertices(:,1),vertices(:,2))
axis equal;
```

And the resulting polygon:
[image]

If you want to introduce some randomness to your polygons, you can rotate your starting angle by some random amount or multiply your final coordinates by some random amount.

See for example, here I've created a pentagon, rotated it, and scaled it.

```
num_verts = 5;

angle = 360/num_verts;

vertices = zeros(num_verts+1,2); % extra vertex just to plot the complete polygon
rand_angle_shift = 360*rand();
for ii=1:num_verts
    vertices(ii,1) = cosd(angle*ii + rand_angle_shift);
    vertices(ii,2) = sind(angle*ii + rand_angle_shift);
end
vertices(end,:) = vertices(1,:);
vertices = vertices * 20;

figure;
plot(vertices(:,1),vertices(:,2))
axis equal;
```

[image]

You could even multiply *each* vertex by a random amount to get a new bizarre (but valid) polygon:

```
num_verts = 6;

angle = 360/num_verts;

vertices = zeros(num_verts+1,2); % extra vertex just to plot the complete polygon
rand_angle_shift = 360*rand();
for ii=1:num_verts
    vertices(ii,1) = cosd(angle*ii + rand_angle_shift);
    vertices(ii,2) = sind(angle*ii + rand_angle_shift);
end
vertices = vertices .* rand(num_verts+1,2);
vertices(end,:) = vertices(1,:);

figure;
plot(vertices(:,1),vertices(:,2))
axis equal;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I need for my game idea. I will try to rebuild this in Unity. First I need to understand some of your syntax.

Comment: Keep in mind that Matlab is using 1-indexing instead of 0-indexing. Also, the `.*` represents an element-wise multiplication. If you want, you can type my code into Octave online to see what's happening: https://octave-online.net/